# How to solve problem with h5py installing keras?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install keras but have the problem with h5py "Couldn't builds wheels for h5py which use PEP 517..." Is there any solution? I've checked many topics but haven't found anything yet.

Python 3.6
pip 20.3.3
Windows 32-bit

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue, installing `versioned-hdf5`.

```
pip install versioned-hdf5
```

Then install,

```
 pip install h5py
```

It may solve your problem.

Also, You are `trying to 32bit` version. If you `Switch to 64bit` it will be solved.